# How to Properly Import a Module Into A File (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, import

I am trying to make a video chat using WebRTC and Node.js. I currently am trying to add a selectable microphone (e.g. being able to change mics and webcams). I made the function, but when I try to import a function from the file that generates the IDs of the the devices, it doesnt work. Note that I am not currently getting any errors, instead, when I add the import statement to the file, nothing shows up (except for the dropdowns that change the mic and webcam).

Is there a reason that node wont let me import a function?

Note that the file that I am trying to import into exports a bunch of functions (thats the purpose of it), RTC.js. However, I also tried importing into another file and it didnt work either (the file that imports the first file, rtc.js).

Thanks in advance

The github repository is located [here](https://github.com/divinelemon/VideoChatAppSwitchMics)

Comment: Can you share your code where you import/export

Comment: As far as I know, the server is needed only for signaling. All the logic that you've mentioned for changing the input media device belongs to the client-side. Paste some code so it can give more insight into what are you doing wrong.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra the code is located [here](https://github.com/divinelemon/VideoChatAppSwitchMics)

Comment: @AniketKariya I imported the file into [this file](https://github.com/divinelemon/VideoChatAppSwitchMics/blob/master/assets/js/helpers.js), im tryng to import `devices.js`

Answer (score 1):

Export is like this line you already did https://github.com/divinelemon/VideoChatAppSwitchMics/blob/master/ws/stream.js#L34

```
module.exports = stream;
```

Import is like here you did https://github.com/divinelemon/VideoChatAppSwitchMics/blob/master/app.js#L5

```
let stream = require( './ws/stream' );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also ES6 import/export function:-

```
const someFunction = (){

...
}

 export default someFuntion  ( in the case on single function)
```

When you want to export multiple functions

```
export { someFunction1, someFunction2}.
```

Now the place where you want to import

```
import somFunction from 'filelocation' ( note in case of default exports you need to use the same name of the function)
```

In the case of multiple functions.You can change the function name but keep in mind the order of exports and imports.

```
import { myFunction1,myFunction2} from 'fileLocation'
```